# Особо актуально

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать особо актуальный (в отличие от "особенно")? В интернете подобные выражения есть, но мне кажется, что это выражение употребляется, когда стиль более неофициальный. А в таком предложении:

Особо актуально это становится на объектах, в которых возможно пропадание электроснабжения, либо нет возможности подключения объекта к внешнему источнику электроснабжения.

Comment: _Alenka: Можно ли сказать особо актуальный (в отличие от "особенно")? В интернете подобные выражения есть._ === И в словарях есть. См.

**Слитно. Раздельно. Через дефис.. Б. З. Букчина.** (http://orthography.academic.ru/21866 )

Comment: _Alenka": "...мне кажется, что это выражение употребляется, когда стиль более неофициальный."_ === Нет, не так. См. примеры:

_На современном этапе развития лингвистической науки **особо актуально** встает вопрос о соотношении вербального и невербального в процессе коммуникации; Применение данной модели **особо актуально** в случаях, когда городская агломерация охватывает значительную площадь региона; Данное положение **особо актуально** для издательств периодической печати или средств массовой информации..._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если бы я писала текст такого жанра, то, скорее всего, употребила бы выражение "особенно актуально". Оно мне кажется более нейтральным, а специальные статьи все-таки предполагают текст без какой-либо окраски.
А вот в более разговорном стиле такой оборот смотрелся бы органично.

Comment: Да, мне тоже эти аргументы кажутся решающими. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

> Особо актуально это становится на объектах, в которых возможно
>   пропадание электроснабжения, либо нет возможности подключения объекта
>   к внешнему источнику электроснабжения.

***Особо***-то можно оставить, а вот предложение, по-моему, лучше перестроить.

**Вариант:**

*Особо актуально это становится на объектах, в которых возможно пропадание электроснабжения, а также на объектах, у которых отсутствует возможность их подключения к внешнему источнику электроснабжения.*

=======================

**P.S.**

Не знаю контекста. Возможно, вместо *"особо актуальн**о** это становится..."* лучше будет звучать *"особо актуальн**ым** это становится..."*.

Comment: Или просто убрать слово _"объекта"_.