# "Особо" вместо "особенно" — что это?

Tags: грамотная-речь, наречия, разговорная-речь

Был уже связанный с этим [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40349/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE), но там не рассматривается главное, что меня волнует.

У меня сложилось ощущение, что в последнее время (ну, там, 10–20 лет, не больше, я думаю) часто стали употреблять ***особо*** вместо ***особенно***, например:

- Я не особо верю в его честность.
- Это был не особо красивый город.

Поэтому у меня два вопроса:

*1. Действительно это нынешняя мода так говорить и большую часть прошлого века так почти не говорили или для разговорного языка это было характерно всегда?*

*2. Если это всё-таки тенденция последнего времени, то как к этому лучше относиться? Имеет ли смысл этому сопротивляться или лучше присоединиться к большинству (если, конечно, таких действительно большинство)?*

Comment: https://paronymonline.ru/%D0%9E/610

Comment: Только вопрос о наречиях, а комментарий о прилагательных...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, вы правы, наречие ***особо*** в современной речи приобрело **массовый характер употребления и явно сленговое содержание**. Оно используется в таких выражениях, где ему совсем не место, что придает  речи подчеркнуто разговорный характер.

Его **новизна** в таких сочетаниях уже в прошлом, и теперь **"донашивается"** основной массой пользователей. В целом оно обедняет нашу речь, делает ее однообразной: зачем подбирать выражения, искать нужные слова, если всегда к вашим услугам наречие ***особо.***

Словари мало чем могут здесь помочь. Остается надеяться на свой слух и всё-таки **постараться определить истинное значение** этого  "особого слова".

***Особый и особенный,*** не всегда они заменяют друг друга. Вот я читаю в книге: "Они привыкли, особой благодарности у них не было – но обыкновенная, не особая, была".

**Можно ли считать значение слов с их морфемного состава?** Эти слова различаются п**о суффиксу** относительных прилагательных ЕНН. Получается, что ***особый*** – это чисто индивидуальный, в единичном экземпляре, а ***особенный*** – только имеющий к индивидуальности отношение, то есть какие-то отдельные черты. Таким образом, в слове ***особенный*** исключительность признака ослаблена.

Может быть, их так и надо характеризовать: ***особый*** – исключительный, чрезвычайный, не имеющий аналогов, а ***особенный*** – это просто в чем-то необыкновенный.  Например: *особо охраняемая зона* – это отнюдь не *особенно охраняемая зона*.

Но главная функция качественного наречия – это обозначение  **степени проявления признака**, и именно в этом значении отмечено его массовое употребление. ***Не особо рад, не особо интересен, не особо красивый*** – так говорят на форумах. Все другие слова (*не очень, не слишком, не особенно*) кажутся нейтральными, невыразительными.

И пишут девочки на форумах: *Я его не особо люблю, то есть **не чрезвычайно и не запредельно**.* Но и писатели (известные) тоже пишут: ***Он не особо думал о том, куда идёт***, но вскоре под его ногами оказалась асфальтовая дорога...[Виктор Пелевин(1993)]. Правда, это 1993 год, слово еще на утеряло новизны.

И немного статистики по частотности употребления сочетания ***не особо:*** до 1900 года – 1 пример (не особо красивая), до 1950 года – 46 примеров, до 1990 года – 98 примеров, всего – 652 примера. Таким образом за 30 лет частотность возросла в 6 раз.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Sharon! Хоть вы поняли ситуацию правильно! :)

Comment: У вас очень хороший слух на слова. Мне кажется, что я сама употребляю это слово довольно часто, просто не задумываясь, машинально. И это неудивительно -  слышишь его везде и всюду, вот оно и "прилипло". Теперь постараюсь следить за своей речью. Спасибо вам за интересный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за похвалу, мне очень приятно! И рад, что вопрос не оказался пустым. ;)

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, это тот случай, когда новое -
 это хорошо забытое старое. Вот Толковый словарь русского языка под ред. Д. Н. Ушакова говорит:

> ОСОБО  1. Нареч. к особый во 2 и 3 знач. Положи Это заявление особо.
>   2. Особенно, главным образом (устар.). Особо вкусное блюдо. Это мне особо нравится.

http://tolkslovar.ru/o6301.html

Ефремова как устаревшее не отмечает.

Большой разницы в значении у этих двух слов нет - во втором значении оба слова обозначают  усиление качества, свойства: "Особо опасный преступник", "Я не люблю варёные овощи, особенно варёный лук". В разговорной речи часто употребляются оба слова одинаково.

Однако "особо" употребляется в связке с прилагательными или наречиями, например, "особо важный" или "особо тщательно". То есть "особо" употребляют в значении слова "очень".

Слово "особенно" же употребляют, когда требуется что-то выделить или указать на что-то важное: "Зимой в России холодно, особенно в январе".

*Я не особо верю в его честность.* - можно легко заменить на "особенно": *Я не особенно верю в его честность.*

*Это был не особо (не очень) красивый город.* - при замене появляется дополнительный  смысл: Это был не особенно  красивый город (не очень + не был особенным, выделяющимся)

Так что, может быть, это не мода, а возвращение первоначального смысла - особо - усиление свойства, "очень". Я, например, за модное просторечие "особо" никогда и не принимала.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Нет, конечно, я понимаю, что есть и слово "особо", и иногда именно оно подходит по контексту. Я говорил только о тех случаях, когда интуитивно кажется более правильным "особенно".